# Merge two images into single image in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Here is my xib files look like below

[image]

My 2 imageviews are added to view which different than view of xib file.
I need to merge images from 2 imageview into single image. BUT MY PROBLEM IS MY SECOND IMAGEVIEW WHICH CONTAINS "blur.png" IS DRAGGABLE. My second imageview is smaller than first imageview. How can I merge these images into one & use the final image. 
Here is my code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.viewForImages.bounds.size);  
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height);
[imageView.image drawInRect:rect];  
[blurImageView.image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeScreen alpha:1.0];  

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what is not working in that code? What is your problem?